# Why is my dynamically created SVG is different when viewed and different when printed using svg2pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, pdf-generation

I created an svg dynamically by exporting svg of graphs which were inside iframes, and then combined them with a few base64 images of tables(also inside iframes). That final svg, after testing many times, is perfect and as i need it to be. I am using a few title elements and positioning them in the middle, and adding that image after some space below the title. Finally, I am positioning my graphs below these two elements. When I render these on an [online svg viewer](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html), it is coming up like this:

### What I want

[image]

This is what I want it to be. I got this svg code when I logged it in console just before I send it to svg2pdf function.

### What I get

[image]

Now the weird thing is, when I get the pdf exported, it is missing a few things like the title is on the far right or far left, when I have given it an x value of `($(document).width())/2` so it comes in the middle. Why would this happen? The svg output I see in svg viewers is very different from the pdf I get. Where am I going wrong?

Please ask for further information, I am thinking I am doing something silly. Or could it be that exported pdf does not support x and y positioning ?

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvg/1.5/canvg.js"
    integrity="sha256-gS9x7L+zPeuIJQi5Ozx6nkmnAKegHZGdx/Zy/jOs/Ao=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header" id="canvas_div_pdf">
        <div class="header-toolbar">
            <form role="form" method="get" action="" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="row">
                    <div style="padding-left: 2%; padding-top: 0.5%; padding-bottom: 0.5%; width: 98%; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc">
                        <div style="width:30%; float: left; font-size: 2.2rem; ">Test Board ( Global
                            )
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:45%; float: left">
                            <div style="float:left;border:solid 1pt black;">
                                <button id="export-pdf" onclick="return false">Export to PDF</button>
                                <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
                                <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
                                <br/>
                                <h3>Preview :</h3>
                                <div id="previewImage">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a id="pdf-download">Creating PDF...</a>
                            <div style="float: right">
                                <label>Date Range</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" name="boardStartDate"
                                id="inputstartdate" placeholder="Start Date" value="20-12-2020">&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" name="boardEndDate"
                                id="inputenddate" placeholder="End Date" value="20-12-2020">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--success"><span
                                    class="icon icon-check"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:25%; float: right">
                                <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right">
                                    <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--primary" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"
                                    title="Dashboard Settings" target="popup" href="/admin/pivot_table/genericboard/1/">
                                    <span class="icon-cog"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right">
                                <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--primary" onclick="updateBoardDefault()"
                                title="Set this dashboard as default" target="_blank">
                                <span class="icon-check-square-o"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right">
                            <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--primary" id="editBoard" title="Edit Panels on Board"
                            target="_blank">
                            <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right">
                        <a class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--primary" onclick="exportBoard()"
                        title="Export board to Excel">
                        <span class="icon-file-excel-o"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--                                <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right">-->
                    <!--                                    <button class="btn btn&#45;&#45;small btn&#45;&#45;icon btn&#45;&#45;primary" id="export-pdf" onclick="return false" title="Export board to PDF">-->
                        <!--                                        <span class="icon-file-pdf-o"></span>-->
                        <!--                                    </button>-->
                        <!--                                </div>-->
                        <div style="width:15%; min-width:32px; float: right;border: 1px solid black">
                            <button class="btn btn--small btn--icon btn--primary" id="export-div" onclick="return false"
                            title="Export board to PDF">
                            <span class="icon-file-pdf-o">download divs</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</header>
<div>
    <span>
        <h4 id="graph1title">Graph one title</h4>
        <iframe id="ifrm1" src="chart.html" width="250" height="250"></iframe>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 id="graph2title">Graph two title</h4>
        <iframe id="ifrm2" src="chart2.html" width="250" height="250"></iframe>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4>Table two title</h4>
        <iframe id="ifrm3" src="table.html" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="buttonrow">
    <button id="set-charts">Set Charts</button>
    <button id="export-png">Export to PNG</button>
    <button id="export-pdf">Export to PDF</button>
    <button class="btn" id="export">Save</button>
</div>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yWorks/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/master/dist/svg2pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {


    // var element = $("#ifrm3"); // global variable
    var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrm3');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var element = innerDoc.getElementById("example")

    var getCanvas; // global variable
    var imageData;

    // $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
                imageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                // console.log("html div", imageData);
                // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
                var newData = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
            }
        });
        // console.log("html div", imageData);
    // });

    // $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    //  var imageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //  console.log("html div", imageData);
    //  // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    //  var newData = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    //  $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    // });


    var ifrmChart = undefined;
    var chartArray = [];


    Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts) {
        var svgArr = [],
        top = 0,
        line = false,
        count = 0,
        width = 0;
        graphCount = charts.length;
        // console.log(graphCount);

        Highcharts.each(charts, function (chartArray, tableObject) {
            console.log("@137", tableObject);
            chart = chartArray.chart;
            var tableSVG;
            var xpos = chartArray.xPos;
            var ypos = chartArray.yPos;
            //console.log('typeof' + typeof(xpos));
            //console.log(xpos,ypos);
            var svg = chart.getSVG(),
                // Get width/height of SVG for export
                svgWidth = +svg.match(
                    /^<svg[^>]*\swidth\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                    )[1],
                svgHeight = +svg.match(
                    /^<svg[^>]*height\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                    )[1];

                svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g><path style="padding: 20px"></path></g><g style="padding: 20px" transform="translate(' + ypos + ',' + xpos + ')" ');


                svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                var iframe = document.getElementById('ifrm3');
                var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                var innerTable = innerDoc.getElementById("example")

            // var iframe = innerTable; // or some other selector to get the iframe
            var temp = $('#tableContainer', innerTable);

            // html2canvas(tableObject).then(canvas => {
            // tableSVG = canvas;
            // console.log(tableSVG);
            // });

            console.log($(document).width()/2);
            svg = svg + '<text x="' + ($(document).width())/2 + ' " text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:24px;font-family:Arial;fill:#333333;;border:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-block-end:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-block-end-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-block-start:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-block-start-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-bottom:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-bottom-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-inline-end:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-inline-end-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-inline-start:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-inline-start-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-left:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-left-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-right:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-right-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);border-top:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);border-top-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);caret-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);color:rgb(51, 51, 51);column-rule:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);column-rule-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);font-family:Arial;outline:rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;outline-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);text-decoration:none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);text-decoration-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-after:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-after-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-before:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-before-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-end:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-end-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-start:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-border-start-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-column-rule:0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-column-rule-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-perspective-origin:113px 0px;webkit-text-emphasis-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-text-fill-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);webkit-text-stroke-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);" y="19" fill="rgb(51, 51, 51)"><tspan>Board Title Report</tspan></text>' + tableSVG;


            //replace 'Column charts' with chart title element text

            // console.log("@202", imageData);
            svgArr.push(svg);
        });


        return "<svg height='" + $(document).height() + "' width='" + $(document).width() + "' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>" +
        svgArr.join('') + '<image width="500" height="300" xlink:href="' + imageData + '">' +'</svg>';
    };

    Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {

        //Highcharts.setOptions({ });
        // Merge the options
        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);
        svgContent = Highcharts.getSVG(charts);
        console.log(svgContent);
        // console.log($(svgContent));

        var svgString = svgContent;
        var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
        htmlObject.setAttribute("id", "svgexport");
        htmlObject.innerHTML = svgString;
        console.log(htmlObject);


        var svg = htmlObject.querySelector('svg'),
        pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [$(document).height(), $(document).width()]);
        console.log("@232",svg);


        setTimeout(function () {

            svg2pdf(svg, pdf, {
                scale: 72 / 96, // this is the ratio of px to pt units
            });

            var data = pdf.output('datauristring');
            var dl = document.getElementById('pdf-download');


            dl.innerHTML = 'Download PDF';
            dl.href = data;
            dl.download = 'mychart.pdf';
        }, 1000);
    };
    $('#export-png').click(function () {
        Highcharts.exportCharts(chartArray);
    });

    $('#export-pdf').click(function () {

        chartArray = [];
        tableArray = [];

        $("iframe").each(function (index) {
            console.log(index + ": " + $(this).attr('id'));
            var iFrameId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
            if ($(iFrameId)[0].contentWindow.getChart()) {

                var chartObj = $(iFrameId)[0].contentWindow.getChart();
                var xPosition = $(iFrameId).parent().offset().top; // added some arbitrary padding
                var yPosition = $(iFrameId).parent().offset().left;
                //$("div #ifrm1div > iframe").offset()
                //var xPosition = $("#ifrm"+index+"div > iframe").offset().top;
                //var yPosition =  $("#ifrm"+index+"div > iframe").offset().left;
                console.log("x " + xPosition + "y " + yPosition);
                //console.log(xPosition + "ypos "+ yPosition);
                var divChartObj = {
                    xPos: xPosition,
                    yPos: yPosition,
                    chart: chartObj
                };
                console.log(divChartObj, "@328");
                chartArray.push(divChartObj);
            } else {


                var tableObj = $('#tableContainer', $(iFrameId).contents()).html();
                var xPosition = $(iFrameId).parent().offset().top; // added some arbitrary padding
                var yPosition = $(iFrameId).parent().offset().left;
                console.log("x " + xPosition + "y " + yPosition);
                var divTableObj = {
                    xPos: xPosition,
                    yPos: yPosition,
                    chart: tableObj
                };
                tableArray.push(divTableObj);
                var tableObject = $(divTableObj.chart);


                console.log($(divTableObj.chart), "@272");


            }
        });

        Highcharts.exportCharts(chartArray, {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
    });
});
;
</script>

<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

I ran the svg code [in this svg viewer too](https://www.freecodeformat.com/svg-editor.php), and I get the correct output. That means my code is correct, but the pdf is missing something somehow.

Anyone any idea?? Is this question too broad ? or is this normal behaviour by svg2pdf and I should look for another library for exporting?

[Here is the svg output I get from the console.log](https://gist.github.com/rohitkumar93/32d071cfb37a03ae878fe6b65f8410c6)

Comment: can you share the svg?